# jquery show hide right to left onclick

Tags: jquery, expand, right-to-left

I'm trying to get an effect where I can click on an image to show a search form and it expands the div from right to left

Here's the code I've tried

html

```
 <div class="searchbox">
 This is some text that I need to hide.<span class="clickme">Click Me</span>
 </div>
```

css

```
 .searchbox {
  height: 20px
  overflow: hidden;
  }
```

jquery

```
  $( ".clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( ".searchbox" ).animate({
  left: "+=100",
  width: "toggle"
  }, 500, function() {
  });
  });
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: issue is? where your jquery code?

Comment: i've edited to show the jquery i'm trying, thx!

Comment: the issue i'm having with my code is that it pushes the height of the div up as it's collapsing it and then the whole thing disappears.

Comment: read documentation http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up doing:

HTML

```
 <div>
 <div class="searchbox" data-thmr="thmr_80">
 <img class="clickme" data-thmr="thmr_80" src="/sites/default/files/sherlock.png">
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 .clickme {
 left: 720px;
 position: relative;
 top: 17px;
 }

.searchbox {
 display: none;
 float: right;
 height: 50px;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 275px;
 }
```

jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $( ".clickme" ).click(function() {
    $( ".searchbox" ).animate({
    width: "toggle"
    }, 500, function() {
    });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for jQuery `.animate()` method. Their API site has documentation and examples: [.animate documentation can be found here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)